# p:selectCheckboxMenu 'Select all' ajax listener not invoked

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF:Primefaces SelectCheckBoxMenu

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{domain.listaa}" label="Chooese!" style="height:25px" showCheckbox="true">
    <p:ajax update="records" listener="#{domain.muti}" />  
    <f:selectItems value="#{domain.recLabels}"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

In the managed beans:

```
private boolean[] recFlags = new boolean[]{true,true,true,true,true,true,true};
private String[] recLabels = new String[]{"A","AAAA","MX","NS","SOA","CNAME","TXT"};
private List<String> listaa = new ArrayList<>();

public void muti(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    Arrays.fill(recFlags, false);
    for(int i=0;i<recLabels.length;i++){
        if(listaa.contains(recLabels[i])){
            recFlags[i]=true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(listaa.toString());
}
```

So in the SelectCheckBoxMenu I press any button, the ajax call is working, and the muti() function will run. There is no problem.
But if I press the 'select all' (most above) button in the SelectCheckboxMenu, the ajax call is not working, muti() function won't run and the listaa (List about the pressed checkboxs) is not changing.
Why? How can I solve, that 'select all' button works?

Answer (score 22):

In Primefaces 4 and 5 there is a special ajax event for 'Toggle all' checkbox - **toggleSelect**.

Just add it with the same attributes as your default ajax event.

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{domain.listaa}" label="Chooese!" style="height:25px" showCheckbox="true">
    <p:ajax update="records" listener="#{domain.muti}" />  
    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update="records" listener="#{domain.muti}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{domain.recLabels}"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Comment: I have this problem in Primefaces 6 and I cannot update to newer version, when unselecting all the listener is not being invoked. Any alternative to deal with this?

Comment: Thank you so much. The toggleSelect is what was missing in my code.

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
<p:ajax event="toggleSelect"  process="@this" partialSubmit="true" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.

Comment: Indeed, it worked. But only for select all option. For remaining options, another event 'change' has to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a reported issue as far as I know: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4788&q=SelectCheckboxMenu&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary

Open since 2012. Not fixed yet.

Comment: This feature has been added according this post : https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4788#c8