# onchange event in <p:selectCheckboxMenu is not fired when selecting all

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

This is my code:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu  id="myselect" onchange="fixLable(this)" value="#{mybean.value}" >
        <f:selectItems  value="#{mybean.values}"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

I've written a java script function named fixLable(this) that will be called when selecting one of the checkboxes.
it is called in every click on the checkboxes except for the "select all" checkbox. why?
is there a separate attribute for "select all"?

i read in :[p:selectCheckboxMenu 'Select all' ajax listener not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323102/pselectcheckboxmenu-select-all-ajax-listener-not-invoked)
that you can use **toggleSelect** ajax event and then execute your code using *onajaxstart* or *onsuccess* etc....
but i dont want to use ajax because its slower than just calling a javascript on an event.

any suggestions? i am postive that you can add an eventlistener to the "select all" checkbox.

Comment: Why don't you use p:selectManyCheckbox which will handle your multiple selection also. Check the primeface showcase for the same http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyCheckbox.xhtml

Comment: @user1433804: Because it is a completely different component?

Comment: possible duplicate of [p:selectCheckboxMenu 'Select all' ajax listener not invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323102/pselectcheckboxmenu-select-all-ajax-listener-not-invoked)

Comment: i didnt use p:selectManyCheckbox because i want it to look like a dropdown. and the duplicate answer suggest to use ajax and "toggleSelect" event. but i dont want ajax. i want that my javascript function will run in case that the "select all" check box is clicked.....any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be little misleading but you can actually use `<p:ajax>` element to invoke javascript function **without** sending any ajax requests to the server. `<p:ajax>` has `onstart` attribute which can execute any javascript code. If your `return false` from that javascript block, you prevent request from processing, so nothing is sent to the server.

```
<p:ajax event="toggleSelect" onstart="fixLable(this); return false" />
```