# How to filter a p:dataTable with selectionMode with p:selectCheckboxMenu?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, filtering

I'm trying to filter a `p:dataTable` with Primefaces component `p:selectCheckboxMenu` in one column header. This however, does not work as intended. The other filters on the datatable work just fine, such as input fields.
The column in question is the `Room type`, that has the `p:selectCheckboxMenu`.

The filtering works **once**, after that checking or unchecking boxes on the selectCheckbox menu doesn't add or remove any filtering on the table.

Here's an interesting bit on the problem:

If I remove the `selectionMode="single"` attribute from the `datatable`, then the sorting works even after the first checkBox toggle. As in, I can toggle and untoggle a box and the `p:dataTable` gets filtered accordingly. But, I need the selection mode here, since I'm supposed to be able to select a row and navigate to another view by clicking it. That doesn't work when there's no `selectionMode` attribute on the `datatable`.

Here's my datatable:

```
<div class="background">

        <div class="freeRoomsContent">

            <br/>
            <p:outputLabel value="free rooms" styleClass="headerfont"/>
            <br/>
    <h:form id="freeRoomsForm">
        <p:dataTable id="freeRoomsTable" var="room" paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                     value="#{freeRoomsController.freeRoomsList}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{freeRoomsController.room}"
                     rowKey="#{room.roomId}" widgetVar="freeRoomsTable"
                     paginator="true" rows="20" pageLinks="5" scrollable="false"
                     paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="20,50,100" skipChildren="true" emptyMessage="No free rooms available.">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{freeRoomsController.onRowSelect}" />
            <p:column headerText="Room Id" sortBy="#{room.roomId}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{room.roomId}">
                <h:outputText value="#{room.roomId}"/>
              </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Room number" sortBy="#{room.roomNumber}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{room.roomNumber}">
                <h:outputText value="#{room.roomNumber}" />
            </p:column>
<!-- other similar columns -->

            <p:column headerText="Room type" filterMatchMode="exact" filterBy="#{room.roomType}">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <p:selectCheckboxMenu  onchange="PF('freeRoomsTable').filter()"
                                     label="Room type">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{staticData.roomTypes}" var="rt" itemLabel="#{msg[rt.name]}" itemValue="#{rt.name}"
                                       />
                    <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="freeRoomsForm" />
                    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" process="@this" update="freeRoomsForm" />
                    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{msg[room.roomtype.name]}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>

<!-- normal input field columns that work -->

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to **remove** p:ajax nested inside p:selectCheckboxmenu? i think filter() function itself fire ajax request. also, try to **add** p:ajax event=filter nested in datatable (e.g. below p:ajax for rowSelect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

Using **value** and **filteredValue** in `p:dataTable`

Use only `onchange=PF('freeRoomsTable').filter()`, without child `p:ajax` elements in `p:selectCheckboxMenu`

Set `value` attribute for `p:selectCheckboxMenu`, e.g. `value="#{someBean.selectedItems}"`

In your bean, use `private String[] selectedItems`, with getter and setter

In your bean implement **filterFunction**, method need to have signature **boolean (Object, Object, Locale)** altough for this example only 1st argument (Object value) is used:

```
public boolean filterFunction(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {

    // instanceof checking probably not needed
    if (value == null || !(value instanceof String)) {
        return true;  
    }

    String valueInRow = (String)value;

    // if nothing is selected, show row in table i.e. return true, 
    // you can play with this ofcourse
    if (selectedItems == null || selectedItems.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    // if item in row matches any of the items that were selected in header,    
    // show in table i.e. return true
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        if (selectedItems[i].equals(valueInRow)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // if you don't want to show row in table, return false
    return false;

}
```

In `p:column`, call `filterfunction=#{someBean.filterFunction}` - no arguments, no parenthesis, no need to use any **filterMatchMode**, leave only **filterBy**

Comment: Thanks! Will try it tomorrow. I'll check your answer if it was correct.

Comment: I did all the steps mentioned here. The filterFunction gets called as I toggle the boxes and that method gets as value parameter all the roomtypes that are showing on the freeRoomsTable. However, the selectedItems String[] array is just null all the time. Its getter and setter is not accessed after opening the view. The backing bean is @ViewScoped. I use the String array as you instructed:                     <p:selectCheckboxMenu onchange="PF('freeRoomsTable').filter()"
                                     label="Room Type" value="#{freeRoomsController.selectedItems}">

Comment: I can't tell you much further without Java code and the rest of page...try to change to SessionScoped just to see if it works. And i find it hard to belive getter and setter are not called at all. Also, i noticed you got skipChildren=true, try to remove that.

Comment: You're a genius. Not sure why I ended up adding that skipChildren attribute in the first place. Probably some desperate workaround attempt at some point. Anyway, now it works! Except... the "select all" option :) It's not a biggie at this point. Any ideas? I'll check your answer correct anyway as you'll add "remove skipChildren" on it.

Comment: I should probably create a separate question about that "select all" issue.

Comment: yea i noticed also select all is problem...try with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24824162/1072089, i haven't tried it. in worst case scenario, you could have 2 consecutive ajax requests, 1st for toggling select all and doing nothing, and then 2nd for filtering. something like <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update="@none" (or@this) process="@this" oncomplete="PF('freeRoomsTable').filter();"/>

Comment: `@SessionScoped` is maybe to much, a compatible `@ViewScoped` should work. Remember there are 2 of each `@*Scoped`, one deprecated the other not. So if you use `@ManagedBean` which is deprecated, also use the **deprecated** `@*Scoped` family. Otherwise `@Named` and the **non-deprecated** family only works together. A very common mistake!

Comment: Also read @BalusC 's answer about scope annotations and which to choose. Link is coming up ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope

Comment: @Nikola I wonder if there an interface for `filterFunction()` around?